# Angular get categories description based on id

Tags: angular

i am doing edit form. i send categories buy id but show it in option in description like this:

**new-campaign.html**

```
    <mat-label>categories</mat-label>
    <mat-select multiple formControlName="VehicleCategory">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of categories" [value]="item.id">{{item.description}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

so in edit form i get response in id not in description like this:

```
vehicleCategory: "4,2,3"
```

but i get categories with get request like this:

```
this.campaignService.getCategories().subscribe((data: any[])=>{
  this.categories = data;
})
```

this is response every category has an id:

```
description: "test"
id: 4
```

so how can i show my categories as description based on id?

**edit.html**

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Categories</mat-label>
      <mat-select multiple formControlName="VehicleCategory">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of categories" [value]="item.id">{{item.description}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

**edit.ts**

```
allCategories = [];

    // get categories
    this.campaignService.getCategories().subscribe((data: any[])=>{
      this.allCategories = data;
      const categoryIds = this.data.vehicleCategory.split(',') ?? [];
      const categories = categoryIds.map(
        id => this.allCategories.find(c => c.id === id)
      );
    });


    this.editForm = this.fb.group({
      id: this.data.id,
      Name: this.data.name,
       VehicleCategory: [categories],
    
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fetch all your categories and store in `allCategories`, then you can simply map the categoryId to the category object:

```
const categoryIds = this.data.vehicleCategory.split(',') ?? [];
const categories = categoryIds.map(
  id => this.allCategories.find(c => c.id === id)
);

this.editForm = this.fb.group({
  id: this.data.id,
  Name: this.data.name,
  VehicleCategory: categories
});
```

Comment: Hello! thanks for the answer. i did that but in response i get correct number of array as undefined. what am i doing wrong?
 (3) [undefined, undefined, undefined]

Comment: Did you set value of `allCategories`?

Comment: I’m away from the computer now, but I see what’s going on. `allCategories is getting set AFTER your assignment of `this.editForm`.

Comment: Move the code inside the subscribe, after: `this.allCategories = data`.

Comment: now i get error in fb,group
Cannot find name 'categories'.